# disable HDMI in raspberry Pi zero with no tvservice

Tags: buildroot, hdmi, raspberry-pi-zero

I'm trying to get my raspberry pi zero power consumption to a minimum.
For this I want to disable the HDMI because I'm not going to use it, but can't find how.
I used buildroot to create my kernel, rootfs and dtb.
I tried disabling the HDMI in the kernel build but it is not possible, menuconfig forces me to have it set to Y.
I tried adding to the HDMI section in the dts "status = "disabled";". It was compiled successfully but no change in power consumption.
I thought maybe I can add something in boot/config.txt but couldn't find anything disabling HDMI from the rpi documentation [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md).
I know in a raspian OS there is a tvservice I can use to acheive this but my build doesn't have tvservice nor can I add it.

Does anyone know how I can disable the HDMI from the config.txt or any other way?

Thanks,
Robbie